# printf not printing from basic C program on mac

Tags: c

I'm not too familiar with C, I'm just working through CSAPP, using a Mac Big Sur, and I've tried this with the VSCode terminal, ITerm, and the native mac terminal:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
  printf( "hello world\n" );
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc thatfile.c
$
```

Nothing prints. What am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to actually _run_ your program. Not just compile it.

Comment: gcc -Wall thatfile.c -o hello && ./hello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `gcc thatfile.c`, this compiles your C code. This creates another file, normally called `a.out`, which you have to execute. You can do this by `./a.out`.

Comment: Well that shows what I know, huh? Is there any simpler command to do both, besides of course the suggestion from @dreamcrash